# Using coccinelle out of the kernel tree

Tags: linux, coccinelle

Is it possible to use **coccinelle** out of a kernel tree using the kernel rules in **scripts/coccinelle/** something like:

```
hedin@home:~/projects/linux/eudyptula$ spatch --sp-file /home/hedin /projects/open-source/linux/scripts/coccinelle/api/pm_runtime.cocci task08/task_08.c -o /tmp/new.c
init_defs_builtins: /usr/lib/coccinelle/standard.h
Fatal error: exception Failure("False should not be in the final result.
Perhaps your rule doesn't contain any +/-/* code, or you have a failed dependency. 
If the problem is not clear, try the option --debug-parse-cocci.")
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

```
spatch --sp-file path/to/coccipatch.cocci path/to/file.c > output.patch
```

You have a space after "hedin" which may be part of the problem.
You can find other examples [here](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/documentation.php) and [here](https://btrlinux.inria.fr/matching-int-variable-declaration/), including how to call coccinelle: